# Who did Gregor bind Cherubael to?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Toward the end (as I remember it) of the last Einsenhorn book, Gregor binds Cherubael to one of his warband ?  Who was Cherubael bound to ?  Was it Fischig ?

Comment: Hmmm, i know he binds Cheru-kun to someone at the end of Malleus, but I don't remember him re-binding the daemon at the end of Hereticus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Cherubael gets bounced around a few times during the events of Hereticus, but he does indeed end up in Fischig by the end of the book.

At the start of Hereticus, Eisenhorn binds Cherubael to his (new) interrogator, Verveuk.

Later on, Aemos summons Cherubael into a random astropath from the Essene:

> I looked at Aemos. 'You summoned Cherubael? It was you, wasn't it? You
>   summoned him into into one of the Essene's poor astropaths?'
>
> *- Page 741, Eisenhorn Omnibus, by Dan Abnett*

Later, after Fischig is killed, Aemos and Eisenhorn work rapidly to bind Cherubael to his corpse.

> It was going to take a while to get used to Cherubaels new face,
>   though. Once installed within the flesh host, the daemon had made its
>   usual alterations - the sprouting nub horns, the talons, the
>   smooth, glossy skin, the blank eyes.
>  But it had not entirely
>   erased the features of Godwin Fischig.
>
> *- Page 752, Eisenhorn Omnibus, by Dan Abnett*

Comment: yea tought so!! dont have my Gregor anymore but i got to wonder when i was reading Pariah what did happen to old Fischig as it seems that the rest of the gang at least gets a cameo in the new book!!